# Can I reuse my Azure DevOps agents with Azure Automation?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-automation

My VMs all have Azure DevOps agents installed on them to automate deployments. We have a need to automate runbook tasks on these agents as well, and are investigating Azure Automation as a solution.

However, I would prefer not to have to install two agents on every VM. Is there a way to have Azure Devops and Azure Automate share an agent on a single VM?

Comment: hi phyxx, any update?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you could test to create a combination with Azure DevOps and Azure Automation.

And the key to for the integration is creating a service connection from Azure DevOps to Azure Resource Manager.

[image]

And you could try to finish your Azure Automation Deployment with Azure Powershell task in a release pipeline.

[image]

[image]

And you could refer to this blog for more detailed instructions. [USING AZURE DEVOPS PIPELINES WITH AZURE AUTOMATION](https://www.miru.ch/using-azure-devops-pipelines-with-azure-automation/)

Comment: The issue wasn't so much how to integrate Azure DevOps and Automation, but whether all the existing Azure DevOps agents we already installed could be reused. But it appears that these two systems do not use the same agent software.

Comment: @Phyxx , I suppose that you could raise a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest?) for your requirement.